# How to make a card clickable to navigate to another screen in REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, clickable, card

here is the code to the card I need to make clickable as I need to navigate to a new screen and pass parameters to it upon clicking on the card:

```
function ItemV({ title, url,verificationId,AttReq}) { //for verification items      
    return (
       <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('VerificationRequestDetails',
          {
             item:AttReq,
             img : url , 
             name : title,
             verificationId:verificationId
          ,})}
          style={[
             styles.item,
             { backgroundColor:'#ffffff' },
          ]}        
       >
        <Card title="Verification Request">
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Image source={{ uri: url }} style={styles.image} />
            <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text> 
         </View>   
         <Text style={styles.paragraph}>You are required to verify this information</Text>  
        </Card>
       </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Post your navigator